# WebRTC doesn´t show remote media

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, webrtc

I am developing my first WebRTC app (videochat), and I am having some problems.

Thing is, I can´t properly show the remote stream on the local peer, but it only happens sometimes.

I mean, for example it **often works fine**:

- between Chrome/Opera for Android and Android/ Opera for Windows
- When I use two tabs of the same Chrome browser on my computer.

  but **doesn´t work fine**:
- when I try to set up a connection between two different computers, doesn´t matter which browser.

The signaling server is built with node.js and the [websocket](https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket) library.

Thing is, connecting seems to be working fine (when a callee comes, there is a connection set up and an offer/answer transmitted).

I will put here my SDP code, then maybe you can help me to see if something is going wrong:

**CALLEE (RECEIVED OFFER):**

```
"v=0
o=- 6054484206475406414 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE audio video
a=msid-semantic: WMS RkydrovqF8H5a1LGU8Bcl0GG1bmgsSHCjKaB
m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:W3ex
a=ice-pwd:V0W/L093KmN2xg3/YNkN8WRs
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256      46:E4:F6:13:B4:19:D6:12:55:8A:56:66:77:34:51:73:5F:CF:A1:1A:DC:00:E9:46:D5:FF:EF:  72:6D:E6:A9:D6
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:audio
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=sendrecv
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
a=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000
a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000
a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
a=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000
a=rtpmap:112 telephone-event/32000
a=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000
a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
a=ssrc:1569538704 cname:SKNCGEejjnbKbP66
a=ssrc:1569538704 msid:RkydrovqF8H5a1LGU8Bcl0GG1bmgsSHCjKaB 9077db38-7e9d- 4c6d-80b8-74c8396f0ca6
a=ssrc:1569538704 mslabel:RkydrovqF8H5a1LGU8Bcl0GG1bmgsSHCjKaB
a=ssrc:1569538704 label:9077db38-7e9d-4c6d-80b8-74c8396f0ca6
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 122 127 121 125 107 108 109 124 120 123 119 114
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:W3ex
a=ice-pwd:V0W/L093KmN2xg3/YNkN8WRs
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 46:E4:F6:13:B4:19:D6:12:55:8A:56:66:77:34:51:73:5F:CF:A1:1A:DC:00:E9:46:D5:FF:EF:72:6D:E6:A9:D6
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:video
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:4 urn:3gpp:video-orientation
a=extmap:5 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc- extensions-01
a=extmap:6 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
a=extmap:7 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-content-type
a=extmap:8 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-timing
a=extmap:10 http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-avtext-framemarking-07
a=sendrecv
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:96 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtpmap:97 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:97 apt=96
a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000
a=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:98 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli
a=fmtp:98 profile-id=0
a=rtpmap:99 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:99 apt=98
a=rtpmap:100 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:100 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli
a=fmtp:100 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42001f
a=rtpmap:101 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:101 apt=100
a=rtpmap:102 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:102 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:102 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:102 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:102 nack
a=rtcp-fb:102 nack pli
a=fmtp:102 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=42001f
a=rtpmap:122 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:122 apt=102
a=rtpmap:127 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:127 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:127 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:127 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:127 nack
a=rtcp-fb:127 nack pli
a=fmtp:127 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f
a=rtpmap:121 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:121 apt=127
a=rtpmap:125 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:125 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:125 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:125 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:125 nack
a=rtcp-fb:125 nack pli
a=fmtp:125 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=42e01f
a=rtpmap:107 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:107 apt=125
a=rtpmap:108 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:108 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:108 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:108 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:108 nack
a=rtcp-fb:108 nack pli
a=fmtp:108 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=4d0032
a=rtpmap:109 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:109 apt=108
a=rtpmap:124 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:124 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:124 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:124 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:124 nack
a=rtcp-fb:124 nack pli
a=fmtp:124 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=640032
a=rtpmap:120 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:120 apt=124
a=rtpmap:123 red/90000
a=rtpmap:119 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:119 apt=123
a=rtpmap:114 ulpfec/90000
a=ssrc-group:FID 1391635065 3022413398
a=ssrc:1391635065 cname:SKNCGEejjnbKbP66
a=ssrc:1391635065 msid:RkydrovqF8H5a1LGU8Bcl0GG1bmgsSHCjKaB f8c6a0bd-4438-495c-895e-0f4180112cea
a=ssrc:1391635065 mslabel:RkydrovqF8H5a1LGU8Bcl0GG1bmgsSHCjKaB
a=ssrc:1391635065 label:f8c6a0bd-4438-495c-895e-0f4180112cea
a=ssrc:3022413398 cname:SKNCGEejjnbKbP66
a=ssrc:3022413398 msid:RkydrovqF8H5a1LGU8Bcl0GG1bmgsSHCjKaB f8c6a0bd-4438-495c-895e-0f4180112cea
a=ssrc:3022413398 mslabel:RkydrovqF8H5a1LGU8Bcl0GG1bmgsSHCjKaB
a=ssrc:3022413398 label:f8c6a0bd-4438-495c-895e-0f4180112cea
"
```

**CALLER (RECEIVED ANSWER):**

```
"v=0
o=- 7085228660038989257 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE audio video
a=msid-semantic: WMS
m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:xq7k
a=ice-pwd:TJdcAwO4t3idGbRFAzjGxShI
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 F5:95:1F:17:E2:F1:DB:29:78:9A:0C:F5:2F:90:8D:F7:1C:28:A6:40:6A:52:5D:C0:74:C1:CB:B8:29:55:42:5D
a=setup:active
a=mid:audio
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=recvonly
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
a=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000
a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000
a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
a=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000
a=rtpmap:112 telephone-event/32000
a=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000
a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 122 127 121 125 107 108 109 124 120 123 119 114
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:xq7k
a=ice-pwd:TJdcAwO4t3idGbRFAzjGxShI
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 F5:95:1F:17:E2:F1:DB:29:78:9A:0C:F5:2F:90:8D:F7:1C:28:A6:40:6A:52:5D:C0:74:C1:CB:B8:29:55:42:5D
a=setup:active
a=mid:video
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:4 urn:3gpp:video-orientation
a=extmap:5 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=extmap:6 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
a=extmap:7 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-content-type
a=extmap:8 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-timing
a=recvonly
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:96 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtpmap:97 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:97 apt=96
a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000
a=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:98 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli
a=fmtp:98 x-google-profile-id=0
a=rtpmap:99 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:99 apt=98
a=rtpmap:100 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:100 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli
a=fmtp:100 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42001f
a=rtpmap:101 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:101 apt=100
a=rtpmap:102 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:102 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:102 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:102 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:102 nack
a=rtcp-fb:102 nack pli
a=fmtp:102 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=42001f
a=rtpmap:122 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:122 apt=102
a=rtpmap:127 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:127 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:127 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:127 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:127 nack
a=rtcp-fb:127 nack pli
a=fmtp:127 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f
a=rtpmap:121 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:121 apt=127
a=rtpmap:125 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:125 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:125 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:125 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:125 nack
a=rtcp-fb:125 nack pli
a=fmtp:125 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=42e01f
a=rtpmap:107 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:107 apt=125
a=rtpmap:108 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:108 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:108 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:108 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:108 nack
a=rtcp-fb:108 nack pli
a=fmtp:108 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=4d0032
a=rtpmap:109 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:109 apt=108
a=rtpmap:124 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:124 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:124 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:124 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:124 nack
a=rtcp-fb:124 nack pli
a=fmtp:124 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=640032
a=rtpmap:120 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:120 apt=124
a=rtpmap:123 red/90000
a=rtpmap:119 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:119 apt=123
a=rtpmap:114 ulpfec/90000
"
```

The TURN and STURN servers I am using are these public ones, obtained [here](https://gist.github.com/sagivo/3a4b2f2c7ac6e1b5267c2f1f59ac6c6b):

```
"iceServers":[
              {
                    urls:"stun:stun.sipgate.net:3478"
              }, 
              {
                    urls: 'turn:192.158.29.39:3478?transport=udp',
                    credential: 'JZEOEt2V3Qb0y27GRntt2u2PAYA=',
                    username: '28224511:1379330808'
              },
              {
                    urls: 'turn:192.158.29.39:3478?transport=tcp',
                    credential: 'JZEOEt2V3Qb0y27GRntt2u2PAYA=',
                    username: '28224511:1379330808'
              }
             
]
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in your browser console when your code fails?

Comment: @Ferrybig no, no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://testrtc.com/webrtc-api-trace/ describes how to debug this kind of issue. However, since you said "public turn server" the solution is pretty obvious: public TURN servers are a myth, nobody is going to pay for the traffic your app generates. Run your own.

The credentials you are using are taken from https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/infrastructure/ and have expired in Septemberr 2013.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What is then the list obtained on Github with supposedly public servers? There is is no way to run a test app and use any STUN and TURN servers created by others? Thanks for the links, I will use them to learn; it is obvious I am newbie :)

Comment: This list has been circulating for quite a while...For testing you'll need to be on the same network

Comment: @Phillipp Hancke Thanks a lot. Curious is, when I test from an android Chrome/ Opera device and a computer browser (on different networks), it seems to work fine! I get all the remote media without any problem (most of the times). I guess I will have to start looking for a good STUN and TURN provider.

Comment: it very much depends on the network. Some networks only require a stun server.

Comment: @Phillipp Hancke Or maybe the thing is, I am connecting on a phone which is connected to the same network as the other peer (the computer)? When I try to access with my phone but with another different network, it doesn´t work as it does when I am on the same one... your clues are teaching me a lot!

Comment: Your router probably doesn't support NAT loopback, and that is causing issues when connecting from the same network