# How to stream WebRTC audio through a NAT?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, audio-streaming, nat, turn

I have a WebRTC multi-party app that works on both localhost and on an ngrok.io localhost tunnel. However, when I try and test it with my friend, who is connected through a router on their end, I am able to see an offer/answer exchange as well as an ICE candidate exchange, but no sound gets streamed through.

After first having this problem, I did some research and learned that you need a TURN server to get through a router's NAT. I'm using a public TURN server that I've confirmed works in https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/

```
var configuration = { 
    "iceServers": [{ "url": "stun:stun2.1.google.com:19302" }], 
     url: 'turn:192.158.29.39:3478?transport=udp', 
     credential: 'JZEOEt2V3Qb0y27GRntt2u2PAYA=', 
     username: '28224511:1379330808' 
}; 

yourConn = new webkitRTCPeerConnection(configuration); 

yourConn2 = new webkitRTCPeerConnection(configuration); 

yourConn3 = new webkitRTCPeerConnection(configuration);
```

The sound packets should be routed through this TURN server and through my friend's NAT, but we still can't stream to each other.

Comment: Your TURN server should be listed within `iceServers`.  See also:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCIceServer/urls#Multiple_ICE_servers

Comment: What @Brad said. Additionally, [public TURN servers are a myth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54241007/918910).

Comment: With the public TURN credentials the trickle-ice page gives me host and server reflexive candidates, but no relay candidates. So the credentials are not working.

Answer (score 2):

Your turn server credentials are taken from https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/infrastructure/ and have expired in 2013. If you used https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/ it should have told you this doesn't work -- i'd be rather surprised if it gave you relay candidates.

Run your own server.

Comment: Confirmed: for me the credentials from the question don't work on the trickle-ice test page.

Answer (score 1):

You should change configuration:

```
var configuration = { 
  "iceServers": [
    { "url": "stun:stun2.1.google.com:19302" },
    {
      "url": "turn:192.158.29.39:3478?transport=udp", 
      "credential": "yourpassword", 
      "username": "yourusename" 
    }
  ],
```

};